# how to position a form centered within a div

Tags: html, css, layout

Hello guys I have a small form within a div I have already centered it but the img with it can't be center properly with it its always kinda on top or in the bottom i want the h4/form/img to appear as if they are on one line here is the code:

```
.outer {
    display:block;
    width:1140px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.inner {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;

}

body {
    background:#dee
}

form {
    margin:0px;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
}

img {
    display:inline;

}

h4 {
    display:inline;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h4>Personalize your experiance:
        </h4>
        <form>
            <input />
        </form>
        <img src="zip-icon.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedkna/djhL2z27/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `vertical-align:middle` to your `img` style. This should take care.

Comment: Please check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djhL2z27/12/ and i had posted answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set vertical-align to `img`:

```
img {vertical-align: middle}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djhL2z27/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedkna/djhL2z27/)

CSS:

```
form {
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;   
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
    display:inline;
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align: middle to the img and form. That should more or less do the job. The rest fine tuning u can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using align attribute:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner" align="center">
    <h4>Personalize your experiance:
    </h4>
    <form>
        <input />
    </form>
    <img src="zip-icon.png">
</div>
```

Comment: the img is still a little on the top I want it down alittle bit thats all i was the 3 elements to be on 1 line to appear good Thank you for answering anyways

Answer (score 0):

You have problem here:

```
.outer {
        display:block;
        width:1140px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Change to this:

```
.outer {
text-align:center !important;
            display:block;
            width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
```

```css
.outer {
text-align:center !important;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  
  .inner {
   text-align:center 
   display:block;
   
  }
  
  body {
   background:#dee
  }
  form {
   margin:0px;
   display:inline;
   margin-top:10px;
  }
  
  img {
   display:inline;
   
  }
  
  h4 {
   display:inline;
   margin:0px;
   margin-top:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
         <h4>Personalize your experiance:
  </h4>

        <form>
            <input />
        </form>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O9fPYk5.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update css. All content will be in center as you need

```js
function useless() {
     alert(hello);   
}
```

```css
.outer {
   display:block;
   max-width:1140px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  
  .inner {
   text-align:center;

   
  }
  
  body {
   background:#dee
  }
  form {
   margin:0px;
   display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  img {
   display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
   
  }
  
  h4 {
   display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
   margin:0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
         <h4>Personalize your experiance:
  </h4>

        <form>
            <input />
        </form>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O9fPYk5.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way is to use negative margin (not good for ie <8)

```
img {
        margin-bottom:-15px;
        display:inline;

    }
```